# Remove rel attribute using jquery based on screensize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, lightbox

I am using lightbox for a group of images on 3 seperate pages. I have just made the website responsive for mobile but need to disable the lightbox on mobile.
I believe the best way for this is to remove the rel attribute for smaller screens.

The rel attribute is: rel="lightbox[page-name]" and these are in the anchors within unordered lists with classes of brandingsamples, marketingsamples and webdesignsamples.

I havent got a clue where to start with this so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to simply remove an attribute you can try this:

```
$('selecter').attr('attrname', 'valueifany');
```

In your case it would be:

```
$('body').attr('rel[lightbox]', '');
```

Or a simple one:

```
$('body').removeAttr('rel[lightbox]');
```

To give the condition you can apply the screen-width condition as:

```
if($(window).width() >= 'value' && $(window).height() >= 'value') {
  // write the code here..
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/

Comment: this is not exaclty OP asked.

Comment: @SivaRajini, sorry sorry! I just forgot to write the remaining part! :D

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing the attribute I would rather execute the lightbox script (and load all necessary assets) only if your page is not viewed on a mobile context. This would allows you to save precious bandwidth and make your page faster to load.

You could use a light script/assets loader like `yepnope` that loads the lightbox assets only if a given condition is satisfied (e.g. you may look at screen resolution, or your screen dpi value)

A simple example could be

```
<script src="/assets/yepnope.min.js"></script>
<script>
    yepnope([{
       test: (screen.width > 1024),  // if we're on a large screen
       yep: ["/css/lighbox.css", "/assets/lightbox.js"]
    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: doesnt look like yepnope is available to download on the site, says github is empty.

Comment: maybe it's a temporary problem, try to download it from here: https://raw.github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/master/yepnope.1.5.4-min.js

Answer (score 0):

Detect mobile device and then remove attribute in it.Use:

```
   if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
   $('selector').removeAttr('rel');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(screen.width<600){
    $('a').removeAttr('rel[lightbox]');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: would I just put that in my header?

Comment: I've modified the code on the example. You could use it in your header or in your footer. Always after the jQuery reference.